V2ray Cleanup resources/disconnect issue in Kotlin
I'm having issue with disconnecting my VpnService properly in Kotlin.
Initial Start Service works as expected, But once I stop my Service and call disconnect() to cleanup and then Start it again, Vpn will not route the traffic as it did in Initial Service Start and I get this log:
[693172588] app/proxyman/outbound: failed to process outbound traffic > proxy/vmess/outbound: failed to find an available destination > common/retry: [transport/internet/grpc: failed to dial gRPC > transport/internet/grpc: Cannot dial gRPC > rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: read tcp 26.26.26.1:38964->173.245.58.154:2087: i/o timeout" transport/internet/grpc: failed to dial gRPC > transport/internet/grpc: Cannot dial gRPC > rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: read tcp 26.26.26.1:42536->173.245.58.154:2087: i/o timeout"] > common/retry: all retry attempts failed 
I have tried
private fun disconnect() {
        Log.d("debug", "Disconnect method called")
        isRunning = false

        // Unregister network callback if the SDK version supports it
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            try {
                connectivity.unregisterNetworkCallback(defaultNetworkCallback)
                Log.d("debug", "Network callback unregistered")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("debug", "Failed to unregister network callback: ${e.message}")
            }
        }

        // Stop V2Ray if it is running
        if (v2rayPoint.isRunning) {
            try {
                v2rayPoint.stopLoop() // Stop the V2Ray loop
                Log.d("debug", "V2Ray point stopped successfully")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("debug", "Failed to stop V2Ray point: ${e.message}")
            }
        }

        // Stop the foreground service and clean up
        serviceControl?.get()?.getService()?.stopForeground(true) // Stop the foreground notification
        Log.d("debug", "Foreground notification stopped")

        // Destroy the tun2socks process
        try {
            if (::process.isInitialized && process.isAlive) {
                Log.d(packageName, "Destroying tun2socks process")
                process.destroy()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(packageName, "Failed to destroy process: ${e.message}")
        }

        // Close the VPN interface if it exists
        try {
            if (::mInterface.isInitialized) {
                mInterface.close() // Safely close the interface
                Log.d("debug", "VPN interface closed")
            }
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            Log.e("debug", "Failed to close VPN interface: ${ignored.message}")
        }

        stopSelf() // Stop the service after cleanup
    }

to review the complete and full code, you can view it here at Github
